# How to update multiple records with rails 4 & mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I want to model student's attendance, i am following railscast.com/165-edit-multiple-revised i follow Ryan's first approach and try to use it with mongoid. My modified code is as follows but it does not update multple records, well it even doesnt update any of the record. sounds like mongoid does not found any Student with id of an array. plz see the code and let me know what i am doing wrong.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :students do
  collection do
    put :attendance
  end
end


# model/student.rb
class Student
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :present, type: Mongoid::Boolean
end

# controllers/students_controller.rb
def attendance
  Student.where(id: params[:student_ids]).update_all(present: true)
  redirect_to students_url
end

# views/students/index.html.erb
<% @students.each do |student| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag "student_ids[]" , student.id %></td>
    <td><%= student.name %></td>
    <td><%= student.present %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', student %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_student_path(student) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', student, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

if i change the code in controller as follows than it works but i am not satisfied with this code. is there any other way around or i am doing something wrong?

```
# controllers/students_controller.rb
def attendance
  params[:student_ids].each do |student_id|
    Student.where(id: student_id).update_all(present: true)
  end
  redirect_to students_url
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fetch a set of student, you should try the **in** operator. Try this:

```
def attendance
  Student.where(:id.in => params[:student_ids]).update_all(present: true)
  redirect_to students_url
end
```

What do you think?